# Read xml file and write ids' values into related textbox in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml file named "numbers.xml" like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<program>
<box id="aaa" value="78678"/>
<box id="bbb" value="37287"/>
<box id="ccc" value="783"/>
<box id="ddd" value="7867"/>
<box id="eee" value="786"/>
<box id="fff" value="23"/>
<box id="ggg" value="453"/>
<box id="hhh" value="4537"/>
</program>
```

I want to read this xml file and fill textboxes. But in **windows forms application**  `txtAAA.text` value must take id="aaa" value which is 78678. Likewise `txtBBB.text` value must take id="bbb" value which is 37287.
How can I do this?

**Edit:**

I tried like this:

```
 XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
 xmldoc.Load(openfiledialog1.FileName); 
 XmlNodeList nodelist = xmldoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes;
 XmlNode xmlnode = nodelist.Item(0); 
 txtAAA.Text = xmlnode.Attributes["id"].InnerText;
```

But "aaa" is shown in textbox. It was totally failure. –

Comment: can you show what you tried that didn't work?

Comment: I managed using openfiledialog. So last, I tried like this: `XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmldoc.Load(openfiledialog1.FileName);
            XmlNodeList nodelist = xmldoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes;
            XmlNode xmlnode = nodelist.Item(0);
            txtAAA.Text = xmlnode.Attributes["id"].InnerText;` But "aaa" is shown in textbox. It was totally failure.

Comment: OK, so which TextBox class? In .NET there are at least 3. Specify WinForms/Wpf/...

Comment: Your Window or Form class will have a method to find a Control by Name.

Comment: You need to use `txtAAA.Text = xmlnode.Attributes["value"].InnerText`.  But it'd be better, IMO, to read the XML into a collection - perhaps a Dictionary, with the attribute name the key and value in the value attribute as the dictionary value.  Then you could loop through the dictionary, find the control with the corresponding id and assign the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a list of the xml items and assign the based on the TextBox name in a foreach loop

Assuming TextBox names are:

```
txtAAA
txtBBB
txtCCC
...etc
```

you can just remove the `txt` part to find the correct value id

```
var data = XElement.Load("C:\\Test.xml").Descendants("box");

foreach (var textbox in Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    var value = data.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Attribute("id").Value == textbox.Name.Replace("txt","").ToLower());
    if (value != null)
    {
        textbox.Text = value.Attribute("value").Value;
    }
}
```

Test:

[image]

Comment: +1. I would just change the .Value == with .Value.Equals(textbox.Name.Replace("txt",String.Empty),StringComparisson.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)

Comment: @Gonzix, You could but then you would also need to null check `Value` first, but with `==` you dont need the null check

Comment: Touche! ;) but I still think is worth the effort, just in case the name is not all in lower case

Answer (score 3):

nMaybe this line of code will help you:

```
TextBox textBox = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault(tb => tb.Name == "idFromXMl");
```

In your case, where you have more textboxes I would save the result of `this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()` in a collection and the work on with this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use XPath to find the node.

Then find the attribute, 'value'.

```
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.Load( openfiledialog1.FileName );
        XmlNode nodeAAA = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode( "/program/box[@id='aaa']" ); //XPath Query here.
        txtAAA.Text = nodeAAA.Attributes["value"].InnerText;
```

XPath Tutorial - http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp